# Bitmap. Открыть "тяжелую" фотографию

Tags: android

Делаю небольшое приложение для фотографий. Но проблема - фотографии большого размера (особенно с камеры весом в 3-4 мегабайта)просто не открываются в Bitmap. Выходит замкнутый круг : чтоб уменьшить фото через createScaledBitmap нужно его загрузить в Bitmap, а Bitmap не принимает такие фото. Есть ли какой нибудь способ изменить размер изображения до того как оно попадет в Bitmap?

Comment: [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: Не подходит, там берут фото из ресурсов, мне нужно из пути. пробовал менять этот  код на BitmapFactory.decodeFile(str,options);  ничего не выходит. bitmap = Null point

Comment: видимо с указанным путем какие то проблемы

Comment: еще там вроде как нужно задавать размеры, а размеры (пропорции )вроде как неизвестны, так как фотографии разные. Выходит нужно как то заранее узнавать размеры чтоб потом подгонять

Comment: путь я получаю  final String str = getIntent().getStringExtra("imageUri"); из результата открытия галереи

Answer (score 2):

Нашел ответ, нужно было еще узнать реальный путь по этому методу, так как галерея в ответ сообщает не путь, а что-то вроде  `content://media/external/images/1`:

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    String result;
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
        result = contentURI.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        result = cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: это "что-то вроде" [называется URI](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/uri.php)